# Inserting textarea elements into MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, textarea

I need to get all the elements from a textarea in a HTML form and insert them into the MySQL database using PHP. I managed to get them into an array and also find the number of elements in the array as well. However when I try to execute it in a while loop it continues displaying the word "execution" (inside the loop) over a 1000 times in the page.

I cannot figure out what would be the issue, because the while loop is the only applicable one for this instance

```
$sent = $_REQUEST['EmpEmergencyNumbers'];
$data_array = explode("\n", $sent);
print_r($data_array);
$array_length = count($data_array);
echo $array_length;
while(count($data_array)){
echo "execution    ";  // This would be replaced by the SQL insert statement
}
```

Comment: Refrain from using `$_REQUEST`. `$_GET` and `$_POST` are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you should use 
foreach($data_array as $array)
{
   //sql
}
```

Comment: However there is a parse error just above the line of the foreach loop! It does not come when I remove the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

When you access the submitted data in your php, it will be available in either $_GET or $_POST arrays, depending upon the method(GET/POST) in which you have submitted it. Avoid using the $_REQUEST array. Instead use, $_GET / $_POST (depending upon the method used).

To loop through each element in an array, you could use a foreach loop.

Example:

```
//...
foreach($data_array as $d)
{
  // now $d will contain the array element
  echo $d; // use $d to insert it into the db or do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach for the array or decrement the count, your while loop
is a infinite loop if count is >0